# Saving bert model at every epoch for further training

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am using `bert_model.save_pretrained` for saving the model at end as this is the command that helps in saving the model with all configurations and weights but this cannot be used in model.fit command as in callbacks saving model at each epoch does not save with save_pretrained. Can anybody help me in saving bert model at each epoch since i cannot train whole bert model in one go?

**Edit**

Code for loading pre trained bert model

```
bert_model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=num_classes)
```

Code for compiling the bert model

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
bert_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00005),
               metrics=['accuracy'])
bert_model.summary()
```

Code for training and saving the bert model

```
checkpoint_filepath_1 = 'callbacks_models/BERT1.{epoch:02d}- 
{val_loss:.2f}.h5'
checkpoint_filepath_2 = 'callbacks_models/complete_best_BERT_model_1.h5'
callbacks_1 = ModelCheckpoint(
filepath=checkpoint_filepath_1,
monitor='val_loss',
mode='min',
save_best_only=False,
save_weights_only=False,
save_freq='epoch')
callbacks_2 = ModelCheckpoint(
filepath=checkpoint_filepath_2,
monitor='val_loss',
mode='min',
save_best_only=True)


es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, 
patience=5)
hist = bert_model.fit([train1_input_ids, train1_attention_masks],
                   y_train1, batch_size=16, epochs=1,validation_data= 
([val_input_ids, val_attention_masks], y_val), 
                   callbacks 
 [es,callbacks_1,callbacks_2,history_logger])


min_val_score = min(hist.history['val_loss'])
print ("\nMinimum validation loss = ", min_val_score)

bert_model.save_pretrained("callbacks_models/Complete_BERT_model_1.h5")
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant code snippet that shows your current setup, and explains how you are currently saving the model.

Comment: I editted the post. I recently found out that saving weights at each epoch and the loading pretrained bert from the transformers is the solution it. But that creates another issue that my validation accuracy and loss remains constant through out the training when i load model weights and model for further training. It also gives error while testing with the test dataset.

Comment: In that case, I highly recommend to self-answer your question with a more detailed explanation of how you fixed the problem *initially stated*. As for anything else, I suggest opening a new question :)

Comment: can you please check if there is another way of saving the model

Comment: What is wrong with the solution that you found yourself?

Comment: It makes my validation loss and accuracy constant as well as I can not apply my model on test dataset, It gives the error which means that i cannot actually test the performance of my model